# how do i clear the screen of a calculator in php

Tags: php

i'm trying to find a way to erase the text screen from my calculator when you press the +/- button so it acts more like a real calculator.
i'm pretty new to php (a week or two) so i'm still learning but i cant figure this out.

the php file returns html code where in i have a `<input type='text' named result value='$value'>`
(calculator screen).

and a series of submit buttons with a name and value of 1,2,3,+,...
when i press a button a char gets added to the string in result.
when i press on the '=' button it reads the string with `eval();`
and calculates it.
iv'e tried with a function but i cant figure it out some ideas or tips would be very much welcome.

```
$value = '';
if(isset($_GET['result']))
$value.=$_GET['result'];

if(isset($_GET['1']))
    $value .='1';
    if(isset($_GET['2']))
    $value .='2';

//and so on ...
```

```
if(isset($_GET['+']))
  $value .='+';
  if(isset($_GET['-']))
  $value .='-';
  if(isset($_GET['='])){
      eval('$result = '.$value.';');
      $value = $result;}

return "<form action='index.php' method='get'>
<br><input type='text'   name='result' value='$value'><br>
<input type='submit' name='1' value='1'>
<input type='submit' name='2' value='2'>
//and so on ...
```

(the rest of the html code is loaded somewhere else)

Comment: When you want to reset the result: `unset($_GET['result'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP code below will execute JavaScript code to clean the input field,

```
echo"<script>document.getElementsByName('result')[0].value = '';</script>
```

This should resolve your question but i have to tell you that PHP isn't suitable choice to make a web calculator, You need to use JavaScript to make a real calculator without refreshing the page.

Please copy this code below to an HTML file and try it so you can get an idea how it works.

```
First Number
<input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="6" /><br>
Second Number
<input type="text" id="secondNumber" value="5" /><br>
Result
<input type="text" id="result" /><br>
<button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
<script>
    function Calculate(){
        let firstNumber;
        let secondNumber;
        firstNumber  = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        document.getElementById("result").value = Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber);
        // "Number" is to tell javascript its a number not a string/text,
        // without "Number" it will concat both numbers
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use brackets for your conditions, especially if you nest them:

```
if(isset($_GET['result'])) {
    $value .= $_GET['result'];
}
```

And your indentation makes it look like Python, someone reading it would mistake it for a condition nested in another condition and believe that your if(isset($_GET['2'])) is true only if if(isset($_GET['1'])) is also true.
A switch is a better solution here (and even better for the operators since you probably only have four of them), but in any case, you should assign each term of your operation in a single variable.